# ‘RSA_SSLV23_PADDING’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘RSA_NO_PADDING’? While compiling ruby-2.7.1 using asdf

Tags: c, ruby, openssl, asdf

I am getting this issue while compiling ruby-2.7.1 using asdf or rvm.

It is even causing issues in erlang installation as well.

Error could be

```
generating x86_64-linux-fake.rb
x86_64-linux-fake.rb updated
./miniruby -I./lib -I. -I.ext/common  ./tool/runruby.rb --extout=.ext  -- --disable-gems -r./x86_64-linux-fake ./tool/rbinstall.rb --make="make" --dest-dir="" --extout=".ext" --mflags="" --make-flags="" --data-mode=0644 --prog-mode=0755 --installed-list .installed.list --mantype="doc" --rdoc-output=".ext/rdoc" --html-output=".ext/html"
/tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/.ext/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/.ext/common/openssl.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/security.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/package.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/installer.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20220515222647.5893.R2e2fF/ruby-2.7.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:713:in `<module:RbInstall>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:649:in `<main>'
make: *** [uncommon.mk:373: do-install-all] Error 1
```

OR

```
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:877:58: error: ‘RSA_SSLV23_PADDING’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘RSA_NO_PADDING’?
  877 | #define DefRSAConst(x) rb_define_const(cRSA, #x, INT2NUM(RSA_##x))
      |                                                          ^~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:262:33: note: in definition of macro ‘RB_INT2FIX’
  262 | #define RB_INT2FIX(i) (((VALUE)(i))<<1 | RUBY_FIXNUM_FLAG)
      |                                 ^
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1609:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘RB_INT2NUM’
 1609 | #define INT2NUM(x) RB_INT2NUM(x)
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:877:50: note: in expansion of macro ‘INT2NUM’
  877 | #define DefRSAConst(x) rb_define_const(cRSA, #x, INT2NUM(RSA_##x))
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:942:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘DefRSAConst’
  942 |     DefRSAConst(SSLV23_PADDING);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:877:58: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  877 | #define DefRSAConst(x) rb_define_const(cRSA, #x, INT2NUM(RSA_##x))
      |                                                          ^~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:262:33: note: in definition of macro ‘RB_INT2FIX’
  262 | #define RB_INT2FIX(i) (((VALUE)(i))<<1 | RUBY_FIXNUM_FLAG)
      |                                 ^
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1609:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘RB_INT2NUM’
 1609 | #define INT2NUM(x) RB_INT2NUM(x)
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:877:50: note: in expansion of macro ‘INT2NUM’
  877 | #define DefRSAConst(x) rb_define_const(cRSA, #x, INT2NUM(RSA_##x))
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:942:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘DefRSAConst’
  942 |     DefRSAConst(SSLV23_PADDING);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
ossl_pkey.c: At top level
```

I tried installing openssl version 1.1 using apt-get but it is not working.

Answer (score 11):

I usually use a solution like this when I encounter openssl issues while compiling Ruby. I prefer not to mess with the OS's installed version if I can help it, and I don't use anything like RVM.

1. Download the latest version ~1.1 of Open SSL:

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz
```

2. Extract and configure to install somewhere on your system, then compile and install. In my case it goes in my home dir since I do a lot of Ruby development and ruby is also going in my home dir.

```
tar xvzf openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1q
mkdir -p $HOME/lib/openssl
./config --prefix=$HOME/lib/openssl
make
make install
```

3. Make sure your openssl folder has the proper certs.

```
cp /etc/ssl/certs/* $HOME/lib/openssl/ssl/certs
```

4. Compile ruby like so. Remember that this is specific for my own home directory, you could just as easily install this as a systemwide ruby.

```
tar xvzf ruby-2.7.1.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.7.1
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.rubies/ruby-2.7.1 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/lib/openssl
make
make install
```

Comment: Should be `cp -r /etc/ssl/certs/* $HOME/lib/openssl/ssl/certs`, but great answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Openssl recently removed support for `RSA_SSLV23_PADDING` after [CVE-2021-23839](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/14216)

Best option is installing latest version of ruby, which should have support for this, but I had to install this particular version of ruby. So here are the things that helped me.

This answer really helped me.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126893/how-to-install-openssl-1-1-1-and-libssl-package

And in the last I have to copy this openssl.so.1.1 file (generated after compiling) to lib folder.

`sudo cp openssl.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib/`

or

`sudo cp openssl.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib64/`

then `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64`
and `sudo ldconfig`

Now try to run `asdf install ruby-2.7.1`

It should be working.

Comment: `RSA_SSLV23_PADDING` was removed in [`3.0.0`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/b0aae913246af1d07e728d24f53f55028f61c696) I guess. Or see the [changelog](https://www.openssl.org/news/cl30.txt) (Changes between `1.1.1` and `3.0.0` [7 sep 2021], Removed RSA padding mode for `SSLv23`).

Answer (score 1):

<del>Found simple solution here: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5216#issuecomment-1206488598</del>

<del>You need to:</del>

<del>`rvm pkg install openssl`</del>

<del>and then run:</del>

<del>`rvm install ruby-2.7.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/share/rvm/usr`</del>

<del>Ruby will be compiled using internal rvm openssl in version 1.0.2, so no longer RSA_SSLV23_PADDING error.</del>

Soon after posting this answer I found out that there are some issues when using ruby 2.7.x compiled with `openssl 1.0.2`. I experienced issues with installing/running `pq` gem due to mismatching openssl versions (this gem uses 1.1.1).

There were not such problems when ruby has been compiled with `openssl 1.1.1`, so I strongly recommend to look at **Jon Jenkins** answer.

Comment: Good solution! I needed to use `rvm pkg install openssl`.

Comment: Should it not be --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr ?

Answer (score 1):

If you run into this issue while attempting to install an older version of Ruby with asdf on macOS, there's no need to uninstall openssl@3 or build OpenSSL yourself.

Make sure you have openssl@1.1 installed with Homebrew (`brew install openssl@1.1`); it can live alongside openssl@3 without any problems. Then, set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable to the location of the pkg-confg `*.pc` files for openssl@1.1 when using asdf to install Ruby.

For example:

```bash
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib/pkgconfig" \
  asdf install ruby 3.0.2
```

This should allow you to install Ruby without getting the "use of undeclared identifier 'RSA_SSLV23_PADDING'" errors.

Answer (score 0):

Fresh to ruby, try everything finally solved:

1. `brew uninstall openssl@3` to remove invalid openssl version.
2. `brew install openssl@1.1` to install openssl with 1.1 version.

Comment: This might work, but is very much not recommended. You might break a bunch of other stuff by downgrading from openssl v3. You should try install openssl 1.1 separately and link to it on the build configuration, as recommended on other answers.