# RVM error while running make install in ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm

While installing the ruby 2.7.2 I'm getting this error:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j10',
please read /Users/rifa.fauzi/.rvm/log/1692949367_ruby-2.7.2/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

And when I checked the `make.log` file, here's the `error`:
[image]

```
    CFLAGS = -w -ggdb3 -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -std=gnu99  -fno-common -pipe 
compiling error.c
compiling regerror.c
./miniruby -I./lib -I. -I.ext/common  ./tool/transform_mjit_header.rb "gcc  -w -ggdb3 -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -std=gnu99  -fno-common -pipe " rb_mjit_header.h .ext/include/arm64-darwin22/rb_mjit_min_header-2.7.2.h
compiling dataerror.c
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:942:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'RSA_SSLV23_PADDING'
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [ossl_pkey_rsa.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Fyi, I installed the ruby using RVM (rvm install 2.7.2) from this: https://rvm.io/rvm/security#alternatives

I already googling about the errors, but still can't find any solution.

Comment: Do you specifically need 2.7.2, or can you try the latest patch version, 2.7.8? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72250612

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL installed? What version? Hint: Ruby 2.7 doesn't support OpenSSL 3 will require `openssl@1.1`.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I can solve this problem by following this: https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/issues/409#issuecomment-926767470

In my Mac, the default OpenSSL is version 3 and if based on **spickermann** answer, Ruby 2.7.x doesn't support OpenSSL 3 and will require OpenSSL 1. Then to fix this issue, you need to uninstall your OpenSSL 3:

- `brew uninstall openssl`
- `brew uninstall openssl@3`
- `brew uninstall openssl@1.1`

Then install OpenSSL 1 using brew:

- `brew install openssl@1.1`

Last, install your ruby 2.7.2 using rvm and OpenSSL 1:

- `rvm install 2.7.2 -- --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)`

This solved my issue.

Comment: We should not uninstall openssl@3. This could break other programs from function. Answer from @aredridel is more accurate.

Answer (score 9):

Since openssl 3 is required for many many apps, you want to show ruby how to find the right version without disturbing it:

```
brew install openssl@1.1
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib/pkgconfig rvm install 2.7.2
```

The reason it sucks is there’s two ways to look for C libraries on unix systems: try a standard name, or specify some paths to both header files (-I flags to the compiler) and library paths (-L flags to the compiler). Since there’s TWO paths you need to be successful, and if they mismatch versions you can get all kinds of errors that are relatively obtuse, someone invented a script called pkg-config that if you run `pkg-config --libs openssl` it’ll give you the flags for linking openssl at the end, and `pkg-config --cflags openssl` the flags for compiling source files that use openssl.

Ruby’s `--with-openssl-dir` sets the directory for the first thing: manually -L and -I to the compiler. A bit old school, a common way to do stuff prior to pkg-config. It started with autoconf as far as I know, and ruby copied its homework. All well and good.

The extconf.rb for the openssl extension is trying to do All The Things: “if it’s windows, try this, if there’s a pkgconfig file, use that, if not, use the --with-openssl-dir flags, if not, try the usual locations, hope we get something that works”

And you might notice that pkgconfig comes first there. So that with flag does nothing at all … if your openssl has pkgconfig.

I think that was added in openssl 1.1.

So 1.0 would work fine when it was the main openssl. 1.1 worked fine when it was the main one. Once openssl 2 and 3 came out, 1.1's pkgconfig file got hidden in its private homebrew directory.

And the `--with-openssl-dir` flag, while valid, doesn’t actually do anything if *any* openssl has a pkgconfig.

So, forcing it to use the right pkgconfig with the environment variable that pkg-config accepts makes the ruby extconf.rb find the correct openssl.

you can see how it affects it like so:

```
:; pkg-config --cflags openssl
-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.0/include

:; PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config --cflags openssl
-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1w/include
```

Comment: It worked. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Its worked for me as well 
Intel CPU with OSx 14.2.1 (23C71)

Comment: Life saver solution, works perfectly with Intel CPU @ macOS Sonoma version: 14.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib/pkgconfig rvm install 2.7.5
That one command works for me after spending almost my whole day....

Actually I installed opensll@3 default into mac so that one is not supporting old ruby versions anymore...

So i simply re-installed OPENDSSL@1 then run that one comand that shared above  it works ...

Aaing bundle thanks for sharing it here.!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35704693)